# regex match one string only if line does not contain another string

Tags: regex

Is there a general regex for matching one string, but only if a line does not contain another string?

E.g I want to match the word `apple` but only if the line does not contain `banana`. So the following lines:

1. `apple banana` - does not match
2. `pear apple` - matches apple but not pear
3. `apple pear apple` - matches the first and second apple but not the pear

I know that

```
^((?!banana).)*$
```

will match a line that does not contain banana. But I can't seem to combine that with matching apple only.

Comment: You may just need two regexes. Any extremely pressing need to do it in one?

Comment: What about "banana apple"? Is it a posible option?

Comment: Which regex flavor are you using? Is it PCRE?

Comment: The regex flavour is PCRE, yes. Banana apple is possible yes - I don't want to match any line with banana

Comment: @Michelle maybe, I'm not sure. The application is for syntax highlighting in an XML c++.lang file for a text editor. I want to match the ``/`` character, but that breaks the comment construct ``//``. There may be a different way to approach that problem, but the question is proving quite an interesting academic exercise anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this PCRE regex:

```
.*banana.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|\bapple\b
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pZ3rK2)

Comment: Line can still contain banana: "pear banana apple"

Comment: Whoops, good point michelle, I didn't check that combination. Unaccepted for now...

Comment: failed for "one tow hal banana i apple
"

Comment: @anubhava it seems you've got it this time :D - a few more permutations http://regex101.com/r/sW8eF9 . I will wait a while before accepting, to see if anyone posts counter-example

Comment: @Piyuesh not on regex101, that passes fine

Comment: @Piyuesh: Are you sure? This regex doesn't match `one tow hal banana i apple`

Comment: @JohnnyLyco: In your demo it is not matching all the lines that contain `banana`. That is how you wanted it right?

Comment: @anubhava you can simply use [^.*banana.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|\bapple\b](http://regex101.com/r/pO8tG9)

Comment: @anubhava that is true, good job, I have accepted now. I was hesitant because previous answers seemed correct but were then disproved.

Comment: @hwnd: Yes right lookahead not needed after `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`

Comment: @JohnnyLyco: Thanks for accepting. I misunderstood requirements earlier and thought you want to match `apple` if it is not followed by `banana`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment because I don't have enough reputation yet. But just to add to anubhava's answer so something like banana apple banana will work:

```
\b(?!.*banana)apple\b(?!.*banana)
```

EDIT:

You're right; Avinash Raj's answer looks like it works though.

Comment: still matches ``pear banana apple``

Answer (score 1):

You could try this regex,

```
(?<!banana.)\b(?!.*banana)apple\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pK9wY3)

OR

```
.*?banana.*|\b(apple)\b
```

This would capture the string `apple` on the lines where the string `banana` isn't exists.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pK9wY3/2)